# Randomly add INFTY value in adjacency matrix

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix, random

I want to create an adjacency matrix representing an undirected graph (to implement Dijkstra algorithm). I started my code by creating N*N matrix filled with random numbers. However, it want be make the graph NOT fully connected, so it the matrix must contain INFTY representing no path between any pair of nodes. Thus, how can I **randomly** add INFNTY value among the matrix generation process as the following:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

#define INFTY 99  // Define Infinity as a macro

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
        /* Local Variables */
    int N = 40;             // Number of Nodes
    int SOURCE = 0;         // Selected Source
    int i,j;

    /* Matrix Allocation for edges */
    int *edge[N]; 
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
        edge[i] = malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    }

    /* Randomely fill the matrix with random integers from 0-10 */
    srand(0);
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++){
            if(i == j)
                edge[i][j] = 0;
            else
                edge[i][j] = rand() % 10; // Can I do something here to insert INFTY randomly. 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of infinity length paths use negative values or another data structure (lists of lists) instead of matrix

Comment: I thought about that but you know Dijkstra Algorithm cannot handle negative values.

Comment: So what? You do not need to handle them but ommit them. You can also just use some defined maximum (define your own) - it should not be a problem

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile.  Always enable all warnings when compiling. (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )  Then fix the warnings.    amongst other problems, the code is missing `#include <stdlib.h>` for the srand() function.  the two parameters to main() are unused.  Suggest: `int main( void )`  the variable 'SOURCE` is unused.  Suggest removing that variable.

Comment: when asking a question about a runtime problem, post code that cleanly compiles and still presents the problem.

Comment: the code malloc's several memory areas, but fails to pass those areas to `free()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one implementation of the Dijkstra algorithm.

The basic implementation was taken from: http://code.geeksforgeeks.org/index.php

Notice: no malloc's, no free's, no esoteric code.

size of graph controlled by the `#define V (9)`  so easy to change size

This algorithm is for a single `source` that you might want to expand to use multiple sources.

```
// A C program for Dijkstra's single source shortest path algorithm.
// The program is for adjacency matrix representation of the graph

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>

// Number of vertices in the graph
#define V (9)

// A utility function to find the vertex with minimum distance value, from
// the set of vertices not yet included in shortest path tree
int minDistance(int dist[], bool sptSet[])
{
    // Initialize min value
    int min = INT_MAX, min_index;
    int v;
    for (v = 0; v < V; v++)
        if (sptSet[v] == false && dist[v] <= min)
            min = dist[v], min_index = v;

    return min_index;
}

// A utility function to print the constructed distance array
void printSolution(int dist[], int n)
{
    printf("Vertex Distance from Source\n");

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d \t\t %d\n", i, dist[i]);
    }
}

// Function that implements Dijkstra's single source shortest path algorithm
// for a graph represented using adjacency matrix representation
void dijkstra(int graph[V][V], int src)
{
    int dist[V];     // The output array. dist[i] will hold the shortest
                    // distance from src to i

    bool sptSet[V]; // sptSet[i] will true if vertex i is included in shortest
                    // path tree or shortest distance from src to i is finalized

    // Initialize all distances as INFINITE and stpSet[] as false
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < V; i++)
        dist[i] = INT_MAX, sptSet[i] = false;

    // Distance of source vertex from itself is always 0
    dist[src] = 0;

    // Find shortest path for all vertices
    int count;
    for (count = 0; count < V-1; count++)
    {
    // Pick the minimum distance vertex from the set of vertices not
    // yet processed. u is always equal to src in first iteration.
    int u = minDistance(dist, sptSet);

    // Mark the picked vertex as processed
    sptSet[u] = true;

    // Update dist value of the adjacent vertices of the picked vertex.
    int v;
    for (v = 0; v < V; v++)

        // Update dist[v] only if is not in sptSet, there is an edge from
        // u to v, and total weight of path from src to v through u is
        // smaller than current value of dist[v]
        if (    !sptSet[v] 
             && graph[u][v] 
             && dist[u] != INT_MAX
             && dist[u]+graph[u][v] < dist[v]
           )
        {
            dist[v] = dist[u] + graph[u][v];
        }
    }

    // print the constructed distance array
    printSolution(dist, V);
}

// driver program to test above function
int main( void )
{
    int graph[V][V];

    srand( time(NULL) );

    int i; // loop counter
    int j; // loop counter

    for( i=0; i<V; i++) // row loop
    {
        for( j=0; j<V; j++) // column loop
        {
            graph[i][j] = rand() % V; // yields values in range 0..(V-1)
        }
    }

    dijkstra(graph, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you could do:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++){
        if(i == j)
            edge[i][j] = 0;
        else {
            int r = rand() % 11
            edge[i][j] = r == 10 ? INFTY : r;
        }
}
```

This would mean that roughly every 11-th edge would be `INF`. If you want to increase the sparsity of the matrix you could:

```
int sparsity_rate = 50; // measured in %
...
if (rand() % 1011 <= sparsity_rate)
    edge[i][j] = INFTY;
else
    edge[i][j] = rand() % 10;
```

where `sparsity_rate` tells you how spare the graph would be (in %). In the example above roughly 50% of the edges would be gone.

Comment: Appreciate your help. That's what I've been looking for.

Comment: @MidoKammi I'm always happy to help when I can :)

Comment: and what is `INF` value?  why not just use the 10 as INF?

Comment: @user3629249 there was a typo. `INF` should have been his `INFTY`